# MySQL: Use my defined aggregated field in sub select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that want to compute each user_id's `rank` in comparison to all all other user_id real time. Real-time means when query is executing:

My query is as below, but unfortunately computed `rank` field is not as desired:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(COALESCE(`duration`, 0)) AS duration_total, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM `forms` 
     GROUP BY `user_id` 
     HAVING SUM(`duration`) > duration_total
    ) AS rank

FROM `forms`
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

The problem is on `Having` condition in the internal `select`. Where I want to count user_id that have more duration than current user_id.

Comment: Can you give sample data?

Comment: @cwallenpoole All I get for `rank` was `null` for each row

Comment: More looking for "in table `users` I have row X, in table forms I have row Y, and I want my data to look like <some-set>"

Comment: I removed join from query to make it simple, all I do is on `forms` table